# Regarding the iteration query in node.js with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

After the update request is sent, I would like to get a success/fail response.

Regarding the response, I have to receive the one response **after all update query is performed.**

How to receive the one response?

The following code is my node.js server example.

Thank you!!

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://127.0.0.1:62590/updatingResourceList",
    type: "put",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    contentType: "application/json",

    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success updating the resource");
    }, error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

=========================================================================

```
app.put('/updatingResourceList', function (request, response) {

    var resultObj = request.body;
    var updatedIDList = resultObj['idList'];

    // Updating the user request format
    var idCounting = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < updatedIDList.length; i++) {

        var latest = timestamp();
        var resourceName = updatedIDList[i];
        var client = dbClient.getDBClient(); // Getting Database information.

        client.query('UPDATE testset SET time=? WHERE resourceName=?', [latest, resourceName], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) { // error
                console.log("MySQL : Database resource update error : " + error);
                response.status(500).end();
            } else { // success
                console.log('MySQL : Success updating the resource : ' + resourceName);
                response.status(200).end();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending back a response at each iteration of the loop. If you want a single response, then do it only after the loop. In the loop keep track of the results of the update in an array (key should be the `resourceName`), and send back the results in one go, perhaps as a json object.

What you need to decide, however, is how to handle if only some of the updates are successful. You either have to return an OK (status code 200), or an internal error at the end.